# MySQL Procedure skips latest record

Tags: mysql, procedure

I've three tables as follow;

```
hm_deliverylog
+------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+---------+
| deliveryid | deliveryfrom                     | deliveryfilename                                                                   | deliverytime        | deliverysubject | deliverybody             | deliveryipaddress | subjnotr | islendi |
+------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+---------+
|          1 | sender@mydomain.com              | C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Data\{BACBEB1F-3852-4CD0-A963-337CA956879E}.eml | 2022-04-11 12:47:13 | Hmail Test      | TEST MESAJI PLAIN-TEXT
 | NULL              | NULL     |       0 |
+------------+----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)

m_deliverylog_recipients
+---------------------+------------+--------------------------+
| deliveryrecipientid | deliveryid | deliveryrecipientaddress |
+---------------------+------------+--------------------------+
|                   1 |          1 | rcp@mydomain.com         |
+---------------------+------------+--------------------------+
mlog
+-------+-------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+
| pr_id | delid | gonderen            | gonip     | alici            | konu       | mesaj   | gontar              | olusturma | guncelleme |
+-------+-------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+
|     1 |     1 | sender@mydomain.com | 10.0.0.83 | rcp@mydomain.com | Hmail Test | Testing | 2022-05-13 09:37:16 | NULL      | NULL       |
+-------+-------+---------------------+-----------+------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

I'm trying to merge two table's data to another table with below procedure;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mlog_birlestir`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
INSERT INTO mlog (delid,gonderen,gonip,alici,konu,mesaj,gontar)
SELECT hm_deliverylog.deliveryid, hm_deliverylog.deliveryfrom, hm_deliverylog.deliveryipaddress, hm_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryrecipientaddress, hm_deliverylog.deliverysubject, hm_deliverylog.deliverybody, hm_deliverylog.deliverytime
from hm_deliverylog,hm_deliverylog_recipients WHERE hm_deliverylog.deliveryid=hm_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid;
END
```

Created a trigger on hm_deliverylog's before insert event and called procedure as follow;

```
call mlog_birlestir()
```

With above steps when an record has created on hm_deliverylog & hmdeliverylog_recipients it should merge data and create new record on mlog. But it's skipping first record and follows with delay of 1 record all the time(Sorry my english is not enought to explain this situation), let me explain as follow;

1- Deleted all records on 3 tables

2- inserting first record to hm_deliverylog & hm_deliverylog_recipients

3- Expecting record on mlog : not created

4- created second record on hm_deliverylog & hm_deliverylog_recipients

5- Expecting two records on mlog : first record has been created on mlog but there is no second record

6- created third record on hm_deliverylog & hm_deliverylog_recipients

7-Expecting three records on mlog : second record has been created on mlog but there is no third record

It goes like this, it's always creating one before the latest record on mlog and skipping latest record.

I've tried to change trigger's event to AFTER INSERT but didn't solve the problem.

Creating records on first two tables handling by an program and i don't have control on it, i'm looking for a workarround to solve this problem.

What am i missing here?

Comment: When BEFORE trigger fires then the last row (the row which' insertion fires the trigger) not exists yet. Hence the query does not see it. Insert according row with separate query which uses NEW pseudotable.

Comment: @Akina i thought the same but frankly speaking i don't know how to do it because inserting records to first two tables done by a program and i don't have any control on it, i've tried delay but not helped, is there any other way than trigger to call a procedure?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad9feb0f5267e40788209fbc39e038c7

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @Akina i've solved the problem.

My codes are ok but I was making a logical error, i was creating the trigger which calls procedure on the hm_deliverylog (first table),what should i do is creating trigger on hm_deliverylog_recipients (second table), because the application inserting main data to first table first and then inserting recipient data to second table, so when i set trigger to first table it runs but checks the second table but there is no record in second table yet and that's why it doesn't create the record on third table.

When i create trigger on second table it works perfectly.

Once more thanks for the heads up @Akina